# Modular calculator getting data inside a String array

Tags: java

I'm currently stuck on a problem from [CodeAbbey](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/modular-calculator). I don't want an answer to the entire thing.

This is the meat of the question:

> Input data will have:
>
> - initial integer number in the first line;
> - one or more lines describing operations, in form sign value where sign is either + or * and value is an integer;
> - last line in the same form, but with sign % instead and number by which the result should be divided to get the remainder.
>
> Answer should give remainder of the result of all operations applied sequentially (starting with initial number) divided by the last number.

My problem is with the logic. So far I realize there is an operator, a space and then a number. To get the number I thought of using

```
char c = src.charAt(2);
```

and to get the operator I'd use the same thing. Then I'd just use a bunch of if-else statements to figure out the rest. But how do I do this in the large scale? How do I read all of those numbers in and do it for every one of them? A nudge on the right direction would help.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Challenge14 {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter Your first number: ");
        int x = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            String[] s = new String[i];

            s = in.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *large scale*? You should solve it for 1 set of operation and numbers and then repeat it for each line.

Comment: What about `Integer.parseInt` or the `Scanner` object? You probably want to *split* on *whitespace*, not just a single space character.

Comment: Ya that's what I mean. For the problem I was thinking of putting all the given rows in a string and then pluck out the operator and numbers one by one. But when I try doing that I get an error. `  for(int i = 0;i<7;i++){String[] s = new String[i]}`

Comment: And the error being? Could you show some code?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a semicolon in your `new String[i];`

Comment: \\s*([+-*/])\\s+(\\d+)\\s* ... but that may be a bit too advanced (regex)

Comment: Here is the entire thing so far. `import java.util.Scanner;

public class Challenge14{

 static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 
 public static void main(String [] args){
  
  System.out.println("Enter Your first number: " );
  int x = in.nextInt();
  
  
  
  for(int i = 0; i< 7; i++){
   
   String[] s = new String[i];
   
   s = in.nextLine();
   
   
  }
  
  
 }
}'

Comment: Could you add this piece of code with the entire error in the question for clarity?

Comment: Alright, Sorry(first time posting in this site)

Comment: Since you don't know how many lines there will be, don't use a `for` loop, use a [`do...while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Can anyone tell me how `5 + 3 * 7 + 10 * 2 * 3 + 1 % 11` can be equals to `1`? This is according to the question from the link provided by OP.

Comment: @user3437460:  Instead of doing this with regards to operator priority, you're performing the operations from left to right.  It results in 1.

Comment: What happens is you follow the operator, aka add and multiply right at the modular operator you dive what you got by 11 and the remainder is 1

Comment: @Makoto I see, thanks. In that case, it is quite easy then..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the more helpful classes for this problem is the Scanner.

The Scanner documentation is located at:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

The Scanner can be set to read from a String, File, or Input Stream.

The Scanner has several useful methods, including:

- hasNext(), which lets you know if there are any other operators or numbers to pick up
- next(), which will read the next token as a String
- nextInt(), which will read the next token as an int

You can use the scanner to pick up the first number, then use some sort of loop to perform operations on that number until there are no more operations to perform.

Comment: It's not that you're wrong - you're very much on the right track - it's that this answer really feels...hollow.

Comment: Yeah, I'll work on this answer.  This is actually my first answer.  I just don't want to spoil the programming challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input is from a file, what you want to do is this:

- Read the first line in as a number
- Split the input on each other line on whitespace, so you're left with something that can be interpreted as an operator, and something that can be interpreted as a number
- Perform the operations and accumulate your result

The file portion is likely what you're struggling with. The answer below addresses that.  I leave the rest as an exercise for the reader.

```
public class Accumulator {
    private int result;

    public void readFile(String filename) {
        try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename)) {
            // Unconditionally read the first line as a number
            result += Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            //Now, we need to read in each other line remaining.
            while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] contents = scan.nextLine().split();
                int number = Integer.parseInt(contents[1]);
                // The operator is in contents[0]
                performArithmeticWith(contents[0], number);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

   public void performArithmeticWith(String operator, int number) {
       switch(operator) {
           case "+":
           break;
           // etc
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The input data contains a number at the first line. Then an operation and a number delimited by a space on each consecutive line. Here is one approach to read in the data.

First, read the data line by line, until there are no more lines. Since there is only one element on the first line, read it and convert it to an integer (it looks like all data is integers). A `Scanner` can be used to read the data line by line. The two useful methods here are:

```
public boolean hasNextLine() - Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.
public String nextLine() - Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.
```

For each line after that, read it, and split it based on the white space using `String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");`. Then process the string, and read the next line. Note that `split`, splits based on white space by default and `"\\s+"` is there just for explicitness.

Comment: `split` by default splits on whitespace; no regex required.

Comment: Good point. I just wanted to be explicit, since OP seems fairly new to this.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, I haven't really been introduced on the "split" part, I'm going to research that part and use that. Right now from just reading your post. I understand that you split it from the "space" part thus on the left side we have the operator and the right side we have the number.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is with the logic. So far I realize there is an operator, a space and then a number.

There are several options in Java to separate the operator and the operand.

You can use the `String.split()` method:

```
String[] token input.split(" ");
//token[0] will be your operator
//token[1] will be your number
```

You can also use the `indexOf()` method:

```
int idx = input.indexOf(" ");
String opr = input.substring(0, idx);    //your operator
String num = input.substring(idx+1);     //your number
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach.

> Assumption is that you will get all the values as String array (Which
>   I believe is much easy compare to making a scalable solution).

Here's my code. You can support additional operators easily and the sequence of operator does not matter.

```
package com.stack.overflow.test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Calculator {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] values = {"5", "+", "3", "*", "7", "+", "10", "*", "2", "*", "3", "+", "1", "%", "11"};
        new Calculator().calculate(values);
    }

    public void calculate(String[] inputs) {
        BigDecimal result = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length-2;) {
            String left = inputs[i];
            String operator = inputs[++i];
            String right = inputs[++i];

            System.out.println("left : "+ left);
            System.out.println("operator : "+ operator);
            System.out.println("right : "+ right);

            result = Operator.instanceOf(operator).apply(new BigDecimal(left), new BigDecimal(right));
            inputs[i] = result.toString();
            System.out.println("Result :: "+ result);
        }

    }
}

enum Operator {
    ADD("+") {
        BigDecimal apply(BigDecimal left, BigDecimal right) {
            return left.add(right);
        }
    },
    MULTIPLY("*"){
        BigDecimal apply(BigDecimal left, BigDecimal right) {
            return left.multiply(right);
        }
    },
    REMAINDER("%"){
        BigDecimal apply(BigDecimal left, BigDecimal right) {
            return left.remainder(right);
        }
    };

    private String symbol;
    Operator(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public static Operator instanceOf(String givenSymbol) {
        for(Operator operator : Operator.values()) {
            if(operator.symbol.equals(givenSymbol)) {
                return operator;
            }
        } throw new RuntimeException("Operator not supported : "+givenSymbol);
    }

    abstract BigDecimal apply(BigDecimal left, BigDecimal right);
}
```

> Result

```
left : 5
operator : +
right : 3
Result :: 8
left : 8
operator : *
right : 7
Result :: 56
left : 56
operator : +
right : 10
Result :: 66
left : 66
operator : *
right : 2
Result :: 132
left : 132
operator : *
right : 3
Result :: 396
left : 396
operator : +
right : 1
Result :: 397
left : 397
operator : %
right : 11
Result :: 1
```